# the function of that other than leading clause?

Tags: that

A paragraph from a ACT reading test:

[image]

I don't comprehend the sentence in blue bracket. Why is "that" at the beginning of the sentence while it is not a noun(subject) clause or sth?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to part of the previous sentence “*... what he’d once overheard her saying ...*”.

She had been saying ... “*that* she was an art and English teacher ...”

Comment: It is reasonable, but how come this dependent clause standing alone? It genuinely doesn't make sense to me as far as what I've learned

Comment: It breaks the usual rules but that is the joy of language (not only English) - you may sometimes break the rules but still be understood. If I were writing it, I would have a colon instead of a stop. The colon would serve to introduce the following clause in a conventional grammatical way.

Comment: @Anton I would also find it more natural to have the sentence starting with 'that' as a clause in the previous sentence. Because it starts another sentence I was expecting there to be at least one more characteristic of Annie to follow it. Perhaps "That she was an Art and English teacher on the Upper East Side, her pay lousy; that she shared a loft in Greenwich Village where the roof leaked and that she travelled to work each day on the subway."

Comment: The rules apply to writing for your school teachers and editors. If your readers aren't teaching you or paying you, you don't have to follow those rules, and most writers don't. They make up their own rules and follow **them** instead, because they make sense and the rules taught in schools don't.